# Не считывает вторую переменную, а с одно работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Не понимаю в чем дело но `var from = daysArray1 + "," + daysArray2;` 
в таком виде не отображает даты которые заданы, 
работает только `var from = daysArray1;`

Что не так делает оно и как это исправить?

```js
var start1 = '08/12/2016',
  end1 = '08/01/2017';
var stArr1 = start1.split('/'),
  endArr1 = end1.split('/');
var daysArray1 = [];

var date1 = new Date(stArr1[2], parseInt(stArr1[1]) - 1, parseInt(stArr1[0]));

while (true) {
  var year = date1.getFullYear(),
    month = date1.getMonth(),
    day = date1.getDate();

  daysArray1.push(("0" + day).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + year);
  date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);

  if (day == endArr1[0] && month == endArr1[1] - 1 && year == endArr1[2]) {
    break;
  }
}
var start = '11/01/2017',
  end = '11/02/2017';
var stArr2 = start.split('/'),
  endArr2 = end.split('/');
var daysArray2 = [];

var date = new Date(stArr2[2], parseInt(stArr2[1]) - 1, parseInt(stArr2[0]));

while (true) {
  var year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate();

  daysArray2.push(("0" + day).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + year);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

  if (day == endArr2[0] && month == endArr2[1] - 1 && year == endArr2[2]) {
    break;
  }
}
var from = daysArray1 + "," + daysArray2; // 3

var active_dates = from;

document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = active_dates;
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  todayHighlight: true,
  maxViewMode: 0,
  beforeShowMonth: 1,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var d = date;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var curr_date = "0" + day;
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_month = "0" + month;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    if (curr_date == 00) {
      curr_date = 10;
    }
    if (curr_date.length > 2) {
      curr_date = (curr_date).slice(1);
    }

    if (curr_month == 00) {
      curr_month = 12;
    }
    if (curr_month.length > 2) {
      curr_month = (curr_month).slice(1);
    }

    var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

    if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1) {
      return {
        classes: 'booked '
      };
    }
    return;
  }

});
```

```css
.booked {
  background: #F00!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
<div id="aaa"></div>
```

А вот с одной переменной: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ5pu/92/

Comment: что именно делает приведенный код? что должна делать указанная строка? что она делает на самом деле?

Comment: @Grundy var start = '11/01/2017',
  end = '11/02/2017'; вот этот код разбивает на части эти даты с 11/01/2017, 12/01/2017... и так далее до 11/02/2017

Comment: добавь нужное описание в сам вопрос

Comment: Если ты хотел сделать перечисление всех элементов в массивах, то будь добр сам опиши их вывод переопределив toString().

Comment: @Grundy а вот эти даты уже должны появляться в календаре смотрите  выполнить код

Comment: @alexoander я честно говорю я мало в этом разбираюсь, если бы я знал как сделать я бы сделал и не спрашивал, если знаете скажите как именно использовать toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) ищет в **массиве**. В то время как в переменной `active_dates` хранится строка.

Вместо строки

```
var from = daysArray1 + "," + daysArray2; // 3
```

Можно использовать метод [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), который объединяет массивы

```
var from = daysArray1.concat(daysArray2); // 3
```

```js
var start1 = '08/12/2016',
  end1 = '08/01/2017';
var stArr1 = start1.split('/'),
  endArr1 = end1.split('/');
var daysArray1 = [];

var date1 = new Date(stArr1[2], parseInt(stArr1[1]) - 1, parseInt(stArr1[0]));

while (true) {
  var year = date1.getFullYear(),
    month = date1.getMonth(),
    day = date1.getDate();

  daysArray1.push(("0" + day).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + year);
  date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);

  if (day == endArr1[0] && month == endArr1[1] - 1 && year == endArr1[2]) {
    break;
  }
}
var start = '11/01/2017',
  end = '11/02/2017';
var stArr2 = start.split('/'),
  endArr2 = end.split('/');
var daysArray2 = [];

var date = new Date(stArr2[2], parseInt(stArr2[1]) - 1, parseInt(stArr2[0]));

while (true) {
  var year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate();

  daysArray2.push(("0" + day).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + year);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

  if (day == endArr2[0] && month == endArr2[1] - 1 && year == endArr2[2]) {
    break;
  }
}
var from = daysArray1.concat(daysArray2); // 3

var active_dates = from;

document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = active_dates;
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  todayHighlight: true,
  maxViewMode: 0,
  beforeShowMonth: 1,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var d = date;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var curr_date = "0" + day;
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_month = "0" + month;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    if (curr_date == 00) {
      curr_date = 10;
    }
    if (curr_date.length > 2) {
      curr_date = (curr_date).slice(1);
    }

    if (curr_month == 00) {
      curr_month = 12;
    }
    if (curr_month.length > 2) {
      curr_month = (curr_month).slice(1);
    }

    var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
    if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1) {
      return {
        classes: 'booked '
      };
    }
    return;
  }

});
```

```css
.booked {
  background: #F00!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
<div id="aaa"></div>
```

Comment: ваш вариант работает а если вот допустим там будут и daysArray3 daysArray4 daysArray5

Comment: @kursof, очевидно надо применять метод concat поочередно ко всем имеющимся.

Comment: @kursof, для автоматизации можно посмотреть в сторону [метода reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). В справке по этой функции есть [пример объединения нескольких массивов в один](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Example:_Flatten_an_array_of_arrays)

Comment: var from = daysArray2.concat(daysArray1, daysArray3, daysArray4, ....);так пойдет?

Comment: @kursof, скорее `daysArray2.concat(daysArray1).concat(daysArray3)` и т.д.

Comment: @kursof, хотя да, можно и твоим способом